# How to make a proper C makefile

Tags: c, makefile

so far I have learned this kind of makefile :

```
     finalcode : code.o
          gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic code.o -o finalcode
     code.o : code.c
          gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic code.c -o code.o
```

I'm interested in learning the better version

```
        all:
        clean:
etc..
```

where can I learn how to write a more "professional" makefile?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I like how you quoted the word /professional/. It's a rather vague thing :). One thing you can do is it look at the makefile conventions section in the GNU docs at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html#Makefile-Conventions. That should give you some ideas.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim thank you very much!

Comment: Please state a specific question in the title. This will help other visitors of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want the typical "phony" targets? That's simple, make `all` the first rule (so it's the default) and have it depend on anything you want to have built, e.g.:

```
all: finalcode
```

Then, in `clean`, just write a script to delete whatever should be cleaned, e.g.:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Finally, don't forget to make these rules "phony", so make knows they don't actually create files with these names:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

Done.

---

As for "professional", that's quite subjective, but I'd start by defining variables for the compiler (`CC`), flags (`CFLAGS`), includes  and so on and **use** these. If you are fine with a bit loss of portability, use pattern rules e.g. for creating the object files like

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o$@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
```